# Configure small LAN to WAN network

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

I want to setup a small LAN that can connect to Internet via my ISP's router (I have only one open port on my ISP's router and 6 public IPs).

On my side, I have an Ubiquity Router that I connect to my ISP's router using the one of my public IPs (WAN port), on my LAN I want to use the local IP range of 192.168.1.x/24 to connect a 52 port cisco switch (L2 or L3) and share the connection with a bunch of PCs. (please see the image).

[image]

Facts: My Ubiquity router is able to access Internet via my ISP's router. My VLANs are already configured inthe cisco, every port gives the correct IP depending on it's VLAN.

Issue #1: the devices in the cisco cannot access internet Issue #2: The cisco switch doesn't allow me to define a default route, it shows the message "cannot use a defined IP as the default route"

Could you please tell me, what IP should I use between my Ubiquity and My cisco in order to have acces to internet?

Comment: Thank you all, your answers helped me to wrap my head around this topic, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP address on your router and the ISPs router are the same.  They shouldn't be.

The addressing on the Ubiquity should match addressing for your Vlans IE 10.0.100.1, 10.0.200.1, 10.0.300.1 and should match the VLAN ID for each one of the corresponding VLANs.

Your DHCP for each VLAN should be as follows

VLAN100 10.0.100.0/24 Gateway 10.0.100.1 DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

VLAN200 10.0.200.0/24 Gateway 10.0.200.1 DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

VLAN300 10.0.300.0/24 Gateway 10.0.300.1 DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Based on the fact they are getting IP addressing already means that you have setup the trunk properly on the cisco.

Then the port on your router facing the port on the ISP router should be 192.168.1.(anything but 1)/24 Gateway 192.168.1.1

https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205197630-EdgeMAX-VLAN-Walkthrough-with-EdgeSwitch-using-Sample-Enterprise-Topology

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for providing the link for the article!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add interfaces to the gateway/router for the 10.0.100.x, 10.0.200.x. and 10.0.300.x networks. Otherwise you can't route from those networks to a different (in this case a 192.168.x.x) network.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start you need to ensure you can ping your Ubiquity router's LAN interface, I am assuming it is 192.168.1.1. You will need to ensure the interface from your switch to your router is in VLAN 1 and then add an IP address to your Vlan 1 interface by entering the following command. The IP address must be in the same subnet (192.168.1.X/24)

```
en
conf t
int vlan 1
ip address 192.168.1.X 255.255.255.0
exit
```

To confirm that this has worked issue the following ping command from the switch.

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

I'm assuming you are using a layer 3 switch. If so, you should be able to configure multi SVI's (Switched virtual interface) you will need to create a SVI for each VLAN. You can do this by running the following IOS command:

```
int vlan 100
ip address 10.0.100.XXX 255.255.255.0
no shut
```

This interface will then be the default gateway for the hosts in the 100 Vlan.

If you are using a L2 switch you will need to enable a trunk port between the L2 switch and your router. You will then need to create a virtual interface on the router for each Vlan, each interface must have an ip address on the same subnet.